# Check for "Not in" a list condition Angular 2 template

Tags: html, angular, list

I have a template as below:

`<span *ngIf="item.status !=='E1' && item.status !=='B'  && item.status !=='R'">{{item.status_desc}}</span>`

As above, i have a ngIf condition there, making no sense but somehow it working. What am trying to do there is check "status in [E1, B, R]" something like that. How can i do that in the html without going to the ts file. Any idea guys?

Comment: Just as you would do in your ts file: `*ngIf="!['E1', 'B', 'R'].includes(item.status)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to go to your `TypeScript` source, you can do something like this for increased readability.

```
<span *ngIf="!['E1', 'B', 'R'].includes(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

But perhaps it's wiser to make a variable on your class with the 'undesired' statuses like:

```
public ignoreStatus: string[] = ['E1', 'B', 'R'];
```

and then

```
<span *ngIf="!ignoreStatus.includes(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

but then it would be even better to make a reusable method out of this in your class:

```
public isIgnoreStatus(item: any): boolean {
    return this.ignoreStatus.includes(item.status);
}
```

with

```
<span *ngIf="!isIgnoreStatus(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

Comment: Nice answer Pierre, and we had a tie in our post-time. =)

Comment: Any concern on browser compatibility? Especially IE?

Comment: Yes, you should either use a polyfill or use indexOf instead

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML, you could use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which returns true if the element is found:

```
<span *ngIf="!['E1', 'B', 'R'].includes(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

as JB Nizet suggested.

---

Or you could use a function, like this:

```
statusList = [E1, B, R];
checkStatus(item)
{
  return (statusList.indexOf(item) != -1);
}
```

where your HTML now should llol like this:

```
<span *ngif="checkStatus(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that with template, what you can do is create a function that does the job for you

```
statuses = [E1, B, R];
checkValid(item){
  return (statuses.indexOf(item) != -1);
}
```

then in HTML

```
<span *ngIf="checkValid(item.status)">{{item.status_desc}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe to do all this filters.
In that pipe you can write any logic to remove all unwanted elements.
It will make your code look better and understandable.